# XCode: Checking and assigning split string values to textField

Tags: xcode, split, textfield, assign

So i have been trying to test this out; basically i have a text file included named rawData.txt, it looks like this:

```
    060315512 Name Lastname
    050273616 Name LastName
```

i wanted to split the lines and then split each individual line and check the first part (with 9 digits) but it seems to not work at all (my window closes) is there any problem with this code?

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"rawData" ofType:@"txt"];
    if (path)
    {
        NSString *textFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
        NSArray *lines = [textFile componentsSeparatedByString:(@"\n")];
        NSArray *line;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < [lines count])
        {
            line = [[lines objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:(@" ")];
            if ([[line objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] == @"060315512")
            {
                idText.text = [[line objectAtIndex: 0] stringValue];    
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want to compare 2 string you should use isEqualToString, because == compares the pointer value of the variables. So this is wrong:

if ([[line objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] == @"060315512")

You should write:

if ([[[line objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] isEqualToString: @"060315512"])

Answer (score 0):

If you check your console log, you probably see something like "stringValue sent to object (NSString) that does respond" (or those effects). `line` is an array of strings, so `[[line objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]` is trying to call `-[NSString stringValue]` which does not exist.

You mean something more like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"rawData" ofType:@"txt"];
if (path)
{
    NSString *textFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
    NSArray *lines = [textFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    for (NSString *line in lines)
    {
        NSArray *columns = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        if ([[columns objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"060315512"])
        {
            idText.text = [columns objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
}
```